# How do I install gcc on cygwin?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

```
$ uname -r
2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
```

I don't have the gcc or the g++ command on my path after I install cygwin.  What packages do I need to install to get this command?

Comment: Adding to the answer given by matthias_h : In case you don't have local admin rights on your computer, install it with `setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok.

- You should launch the installer of cygwin setup-x86_64.exe (if you have deleted it from your computer than just download it from https://cygwin.com/install.html).
- In the Cygwin Setup dialog window just press Next, and press Next again. In dialog "Cygwin Setup - Choose Installation Directory" you should select root directory in wich CygWin has been installed & press Next, and again, and again & again.
- Your will see dialog "Cygwin Setup - Select Package", in the "View" combobox you should select "Full", and in the "Search" edit you should enter "gcc". Further in the list below in "Package" column find "gcc-core" row   & change combobox in "New" column from "Skip" value to the version of gcc wich you need.
- Further press Next & you will see "CygWin Setup - Review and confirm changes" dialog. In this dialog could be presented other packages besides gcc-core, this is some updates & you should leave it without changes (my own recommendation). But you must be sure that gcc-core is presented in change-list, than just press Next button & wait for ending of installation.
- PROFIT

That's all. Try to start bash or cmd & enter something like "gcc --version". This instruction could be used for installation of other useful things of CygWin, for example "make". 
Good luck!

Comment: After this process, gcc still doesn't exist in console, any tips?

Comment: As for cigwin setup 2.924 (64bit) select "Install from Internet" in Cygwin Setup Dialog (step two in this response).

Answer (score 13):

```
 $ cygcheck -p bin/gcc
Found 8 matches for bin/gcc
gcc-core-6.4.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-6.4.0-2 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-6.4.0-3 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
...
```

so you need to install the gcc-core package.

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/gcc-core/

Comment: The link is to show which package you need to install. Use the Cygwin  setup-x86_64.exe (64-bit installation) or setup-x86.exe (32-bit installation)

Answer (score 5):

Open setup.

Select Category.

Open the Devel section.

Install the package cygwin-devel

#### 3rd party edit

It could be this one

[image]

Comment: Hello Paul do you mean the one in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct (Although it was 5 years ago that I last worked with it)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. Launch the Cygwin installer `setup-x86_64.exe`.
2. Proceed to the `Cygwin Setup - Select Packages` window.
3. Select `Full` in `View`.
4. Enter `gcc` in `Search`.
5. Find `gcc-core` row in `Package` column and change `Skip` to the required version.
6. Enter `g++` in `Search`.
7. Find `gcc-g++` row in `Package` column and change `Skip` to the required version.
8. Proceed to the next step and install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

apt-cyg install gcc-core

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/gcc-core/

you must install **apt-cyg** command utility:

https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Yes, but where does one get apt-cyg, and how do you install it?