# Is there any C compiler that does NOT come with an IDE?

Tags: c

I am new in C programming, and I was searching the internet for a compiler (for Windows 10). The compilers I found all had a full IDE included, **but I don't need the IDE** (I have a code editor). Is there any C compiler that does not come with an IDE, or at least a way to download one **without** the IDE?

Comment: GCC doesn't come with an IDE.

Comment: GCC (as part of MinGW) and Clang are both available for Windows.

Comment: I think you have it backwards: IDEs come with compilers, compilers don't come with IDEs.

Comment: You can use the command-line compiler of Visual Studio (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @pmg oh yeah, I tought that the IDE was the compiler itself! Thanks

Comment: almost any compiler is a command line program

Comment: `I am new in C programming ...`  and  `but I don't need the IDE` are contraversions. You need IDE with decent debugger support. VSCode is an IDE,

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that VS Code is an IDE. It certainly doesn't include a compiler, so it isn't capable of integrated development out — of the box, at least.

Comment: I have to agree with @0___________ - the majority of beginner problems posted to SO could be solved easily with an IDE visual debugger.

Comment: You'll want Mingw-w64 for modern Windows. https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/. Once installed, you can download an IDE like Codeblocks and configure it to point at the existing Mingw installation. Beginners should definitely not fool around with make files like it's the 1980s though, have the IDE handle that.

Comment: There is a standalone build of GCC/MinGW-w64 you can download from https://winlib.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is going to get closed, but anyway, you can use any linux based compiler such as gcc or clang.

Also, Visual c++ has a compiler that can be used at the command line. In fact, nearly all C compilers can be used at the command line.

I think Microsoft makes their compiler available for download free. Only the IDE costs money. The compiler itself runs by command and when you use the IDE it just runs the command in the background.

Answer (score 1):

[How to install gcc in Windows 10? (the easier way)](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j)
[How to Install the Latest GCC on Windows](https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/)
[Installing GCC: Binaries](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html)

Comment: Mingw32 is not longer maintained, I thought. Use Mingw64. Also, link-only answers are frowned upon here since links tend to break over time and answers should add something of value to _this_ site.

Comment: One up is mine, @Lundin!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install GCC without an editor. https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

To install it, follow the tutorial [here](https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j) to use MinGW, or use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012074/10442089) to use Cygwin.

On the other hand, you could just use an editor that includes support for GCC. It may already be built into your IDE.